# Capturing and Saving Images using Camera in xPages

Tags: xpages, ssjs

I have a requirement of capturing person image using camera and storing in IBM Notes native database and displaying it a field / area on front end (on xpage). Can I achieve this functionality in xpages? Supported equipment e.g. camera?

Can you please guide me is this possible? If yes how it's possible for both thick and thin client.

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards,
Qaiser

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Hi Qaiser, I don't know what you are exactly trying to achieve, but we wrote an article about this in 2013: http://www.pipalia.co.uk/xpages-2/capturing-image-camera-using-getusermedia-saving-document/ Hope this helps.

Comment: Pipalia, will your code work on an Apple iOS device?

Comment: Dear All, thanks for prompt response. Actually I want to develop visitor management system and at reception security incharge will capture image and store into document which will be emailed to host as link. This i my initial requirements. So for I have done nothing.

Comment: @pipalia thanks for reply. Actually I gone through your article before this post. But unable to get much about it because so for I have not used JAVA. Only working on CSJS and SSJS.

Comment: @Howard, unfortunately, it will not work on an iOS devices: http://caniuse.com/#feat=stream

Comment: @QaiserAbbas You can at least download the demo database we have provided at the end of the article and see what this application does and whether it fits your requirement. By the way, Java isn't that hard to use and you can call all your Java stuff from SSJS easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using a web application/ XPage (and not an app) you can't access the camera directly. However, if you use a file upload control on a mobile device (Android or iOS smartphone or tablet), it will ask you if you want to select a picture from the local gallery or take a picture.

I would use that feature to take and immediately upload the picture to the database. I recently wrote an [article](http://linqed.eu/2015/11/28/dropzone-js-in-xpages-it-doesnt-get-easier-than-this/) how to accomplish that using [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/): that plugin allows you to add for example a button to your XPage that says "Take picture" and immediately upload it to your Domino database once the picture is taken.